# How do I bind a servlet to everything except /?

Tags: servlets, jetty

I have a server which I need to bind two servlets to.

The first is the "home" servlet, which I want to reside at /. This will display what is essentially a welcome page.

The second is a servlet which will serve content based on a url-shortener style link code. This needs to bind to any other request.

My problem is that if I bind the second servlet to /* then this also includes /

Answer (score 2):

Exact mapping has a bigger priority that path mapping. So you shouldn't have any problem if you map your home servlet to `/` and the other one to `/*`, because `/` will take the precedence over `/*`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Map specific servlet to "/index"
2. Map generic servlet to "/*"
3. Add `welcome-file` "index" in the `welcome-file-list`